# Slow boot, BIOS upgrade not help, Asus A8V Delux motherboard

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, motherboard, bios

Windows 7 Pro PC, old Asus A8V Delux OEM mortherboard, PC had a lot of boot issues (slow boot up, errors).

```
Promise FastTrak 378 BIOS v1.00.0.37
```

I upgraded BIOS to latest version from Asus web site. (1018_002)
The upgrade was successfull, with default option set to clear CMOS, so during uprade CMOS settings was cleared to default. Uprade was successfull, but in spite of that, during boot still shown the same old Promise FastTrak 378 BIOS v1.00.0.37 and boot process is slow, in particular, when scan drives:

```
====================================================
FastTrak 378 BIOs version 1.00.0.37
2003 Promise Technology, Inc

Scanning IDE drives............................
```

then something like "No drive attached to FastTrak controller, the BIOS is not installed.." then windows logo appears, starting Windows. How to fix that issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling that controller in your firmware (either BIOS or EFI) should solve this.

What is happening is that your motherboards gets power, the CPU starts executing its firmware (often called BIOS on PCs). That includes things like setting up the memory, checking which devices are installed, **configuring these**, running firmware on plugin cards (e.g. the firmware on a dedicated graphics cards or on a NIC) etc etc.

One of these devices is the Promise FastTrak controller. It is enabled and it will control the drives attached to it. However if you have no drives atrtached ti it then it may look for a relative long time looking for them before timing out and giving up.

That gives you two solutions:

1. Attach a drive to it.
2. Disable this not used device in the firmware.

Option 2 is the usual method for obvious reasons. :)